# Background download not able to get error response

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Expected Error response in downloading file with background configuration

```
{
  "ref": "123",
  "msg": "<error message>"
}
```

if creating **Data task** I am able to get error in response as expected 
but if I go through background session not able to get error dictionary.

```
let url = ....
let destination = ... 
let headers = ... 

        BackgroundSession.shared.manager.download(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers, to: destination).downloadProgress(queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility)) { progress in

        }
        BackgroundSession.shared.manager.delegate.taskDidComplete = { _, task, error in // task completed with error
            if let error = error {
                // ONLY can get Error response width code not expected dictionary 
            }
        }

        BackgroundSession.shared.manager.delegate.downloadTaskDidFinishDownloadingToURL = { _, task, tempLocation in
            if let response = task.response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                 // Do something expected
            }
        }
```

**Only problem is not able to get error dictionary otherwise worked fined with background download**

I have also tried downloading through **request** method of **SessionManager** then I am getting the error dictionary expected  but then downloading functionality not working

**Edited** 
In following code it work file for download file and get error dictionary but not getting download file in background.

```
let url = ....
let headers = ...
 let request = BackgroundSession.shared.manager.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, headers: headers).validate(statusCode: 200...201)
         request.responseData { (response) in
           if let resp = response.response {
          switch response.result {
          case .success(let data):

          case .failure:
           var ne = NetworkError(rawValue: resp.statusCode)!
           if let dict = self.convertDataToDictionary(response.data) {
              ne = NetworkError(code: resp.statusCode, json: dict)
           }
            errorCallback(resp, ne)
          }
         }
         }
```

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I might be wrong here but if your API returns a status code of 200/201 when returning the JSON with error message then your `response.result` will still be a `.success`. Thus you'll need to handle the error message in `.success` case as well. The `.failure` case won't trigger in this scenario.

Comment: @Ayazmon I am able to get dictionary in  let request = BackgroundSession.shared.manager.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, headers: headers).validate(statusCode: 200...201)
api, but problem is Not able to get same dictionary in  BackgroundSession.shared.manager.download(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers, to: destination) api ... see above codes

Comment: @Jasmin Did you try accessing `task.response` when you receive an error? Is it present?

Comment: @zysoft task.response is  HTTPURLResponse but which has expected content-length of error dictionary but how to get data from HTTPURLResponse. I don't know

Comment: @Jasmin What is the first parameter of the closure? My guess it is a `Data?` argument containing raw server response, where the dictionary is. Could you please check that?

Comment: @zysoft ```BackgroundSession.shared.manager.delegate.downloadTaskDidFinishDownloadingToURL = { _, task, tempLocation in``` first parameter is URLSession

Comment: @Jasmin I am more curious about this one — `BackgroundSession.shared.manager.delegate.taskDidComplete = { _, task, error in` . Could you point me to which library you use as a wrapper around URLSession?

Comment: @zysoft it's Alamofire

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208595/discussion-between-zysoft-and-jasmin).